# Highcharts mousewheel scroll event in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, highcharts, mousewheel

I have a Highcharts component with a mousewheel scroll event.

Everything is working fine in all browsers except firefox. In firefox, the mousewheel event triggers the scroll in both the Highcharts component and the entire window. I tried to add event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() but that did not fix the issue. Is there a way to prevent the entire window from scrolling when scrolling the Highcharts component?

Comment: I have something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/otn9fhgL/

Comment: With Firefox 61.0.1 64(bits) I don't have any error, the scroll works fine even if its inverted.

Comment: @Core972 Thank you for your response. The issue is that it scrolls the highcharts component as well as the entire window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs because the `DOMMouseScroll` and `mousewheel` events are now **deprecated**, and replaced by new `wheel` event, which works in all browsers. You need to replace two things in your code in order to make it work.

First of all, please change the event name here:

```
H.addEvent(chart.container, 'wheel', function(event) {
```

And then in your `wheel` event functions body replace the delta assignment to:

```
delta = e.detail || -(e.deltaY / 120);
delta = delta < 0 ? 1 : -1;
```

Now it works in the same way on all browsers.

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/d3r8pb7c/

**API Reference:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMMouseScroll